# SQL determine recency of a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 via SSMS and need to accomplish a recency calculation.

I have an ID and Visit Date and I'm trying to determine recency count based on day groups.

The source data looks like this:

```
ID       Visit-Date 
1234     1/1/2017 
1234     2/1/2017 
12345    3/1/2017 
1234     4/1/2017 
12345    5/15/2017 
1234     6/1/2017 
1234     7/1/2017 
12345    8/1/2017 
1234     9/1/2017
```

The final output would look like this:

```
Recency     ID-Count 
1 Day       100 
3 Days      20 
7 Days      50 
15 Days     10 
30 Days     20 
90 Days     5 
180 Days    200 
280 Days    150 
365 Days    500
```

If an ID is present in 1 Day and 7 Days, it would only count in the most recent occurrence... 1 Day.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far or have attempted to try.

Comment: your example output doesn't seem to relate to the sample data you've provided.

Comment: How 1 Day is 100?

Comment: He said WOULD look like people; the output isn't equivalent with sample data. To the OP, usually here we ask that you guys give an sample data and an output based in that sample so the question becomes more clear!

Comment: what is `recency`? google translator say mean `"fresh"` :/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . That's great!  "recency" comes from the word "recent".  It is used in (mostly retailing) businesses to denote how recently a customer made a purchase or interacted with a system.  It might have been coined when RFM analysis was invented (which I think can be traced back to 1969).  One place to start is the Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFM_(customer_value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, summarize the data by `id` to get the maximum visit date for each `id`.  Then count the number of days in the past and aggregate  by that:

```
select (case when datediff(day, maxvd, getdate()) <= 1 then '1 Day'
             when datediff(day, maxvd, getdate()) <= 3 then '3 Day'
             . . .
        end) as recencygrp, count(*)
from (select id, max(visitdate) as maxvd
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
group by (case when datediff(day, maxvd, getdate()) <= 1 then '1 Day'
               when datediff(day, maxvd, getdate()) <= 3 then '3 Day'
               . . .
          end) ;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon your solution works well. I am noticing that there are values present outside of my date range. e.g. when looking at date range form 01/01-03/01 I get values present within my "<=180 then '180 Days'" case. It should technically return zero, no?